# Do I need mutexes for read operation only?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am writing a program in C and I have a function that calls multiple threads.

Those threads will run on a loop until a flag is set to off. That flag is just an int with the value of 0 or 1.

For performance reasons, I don't want to set up a mutex for reading this flag and I don't think I really need it because none of the threads is writing to that flag but I am not sure.

What is your input?

Note: The flag is being set to off by the main process/thread, before I call `join_pthread`.

Comment: "none of the threads is writing to that flag" -- the main process counts as a thread, and it's writing to the flag.

Comment: If it's just an int, make it an [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) one?

Comment: In modern C, If one thread (e.g., your main thread) updates an ordinary variable (e.g., your "flag") without any kind of "synchronization," and some other thread (e.g., your loops) read it without any synchronization, then that's called "undefined behavior" and, to make a long story short, it excuses anybody from having to answer any questions about your program until you get rid of it. They can just say, "Your program is invalid, it depends on UB." Protecting the flag with a mutex in both the writing thread _and the reading threads_ "synchronizes" them. Or, making the flag `atomic` does too.

Comment: And what would cost less to use ? Mutex or atomic variable ?

Since that flag has to be checked at each iteration of the loop I want to choose the most efficient option.

Comment: A read-write lock may be better than a mutex for your situation. It allows either one "writer" or several "reader"s to hold the lock.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I saw your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78136044/why-do-different-variables-in-different-scopes-have-the-same-memory-address/#comment137786825_78136076) when reviewing the question. I didn't get pinged since the question was deleted. Anyways, thanks for the upvote there, I agree I don't get why someone downvote that question except maybe because the question has a dupe and I closed it and answered it.

Comment: @IanAbbott, a reader-writer lock is not appropriate here as the writer doesn't need to wait until there are no readers left. A simple atomic flag would do - and it significantly cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need mutexes for read operation only?

No - but, your threads do not only read from the variable. There is one thread writing to it.

Without some kind of synchronization (making the variable atomic or by using a mutex) the program will have a data race. With that, your program has undefined behavior and could act very strangely. The reading threads may never see that the writing thread has written anything for example. Even if the program looks like it's working one day, the next day it may not. Avoid undefined behavior like the plague.